# The existence of a unique local solution of a system of partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I consider a system of partial differential equations in the region $V \subset R^n$, given by $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} = F_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$.

Each $F_i$ is assumed to be infinitely differentiable with respect to each $x_i$ in $V$.

The initial condition is set as $u(0, \cdots, 0) = a$ (constant), where $(0, \cdots, 0) \in V$.

In this case, can we ensure the existence of a unique local solution in a sufficiently small neighborhood arround $(0, \cdots, 0)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Since each of the $F_i$ terms is independent of $u$, your system can be rewritten as a gradient equation:
$$
\nabla u = F = (F_1,\dotsc,F_n).
$$
If there were a $C^2$ solution, then by the commutativity of mixed partials we would have to have
$$
\partial_i \partial_j u = \partial_j \partial_i u \text{ of equivalently } \partial_i F_j = \partial_j F_i.
$$
If you just want a $C^1$ solution, then there is still a version of this that must hold in the sense of distributions.  So, you see from this that there is an obstruction to solving your system for arbitrary $F$.  However, if the $F_i$ satisfy this condition, then you can use one of the versions of the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)#Infinite_dimensions) (probably the infinite dimensional formulation on wikipedia is the clearest connection to what you want, but it's significantly more general) to get your local solution $u$.